# What is the current status of research on the von Neumann's inequality for $n \ge 3$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, open-problems

**Problem**

Let $(T_1, \ldots, T_n)$ be a tuple of commuting contractions in Hilbert space $H$.

Does a constant $C_n \ge 1$ exist, for which it would be true, that:

$$\forall_{p \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]} \quad \| p(T_1, \ldots, T_n) \|  \le  \ C_n  \sup_{(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in \overline{\mathbb{D}^n}} | p (z_1, \ldots, z_n) |$$

---

I've heard numerous anecdotes from professors and other scientific employees, that there has been some more recent results in this field. One of them being "using graph theory for $n \ge 3$", and the other one "using spectral theory". I couldn't find anything new, the only "newest" thing is Shalit's work from 2021 if I remember correctly.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Is this the 2021 paper you mention? [arXiv:2109.08550](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.08550) -- a 2023 follow-up is [arXiv:2310.12908](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.12908)

Comment: No, I meant this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05596. But thanks for sending these papers, I will read them (especially the 2023. Piekarz was holding a presentation at the Jagiellonian University in December and I wanted to attend it but unfortunately I felt ill and couldn't). Do you maybe have any idea about what the professors I've met meant with proving the von Neumann's inequality "using graph theory" or "spectral theory"? They're also very recent results apparently

Comment: In this very recent paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.14548 it is proved that the Von Neumann inequality holds up to a constant for three commuting contractions and for all homogeneous polynomials. I think this is pretty much the best known result.

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician Thank you very much.